# Accessing downloaded Imagenet 2012 database using Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, imagenet

I want to load the imagenet database 2012 version using the tensorflow 2.0 library. I followed the steps mentioned in [Preparing the ImageNet dataset with TensorFlow](https://towardsdatascience.com/preparing-the-imagenet-dataset-with-tensorflow-c681916014ee).

My final code is as follows:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import os

dataset_dir = '/home/imagenet'  # directory where you downloaded the tar files to
temp_dir = '/home/temp'  # a temporary directory where the data will be stored intermediately

download_config = tfds.download.DownloadConfig(
    extract_dir=os.path.join(temp_dir, 'extracted'),
    manual_dir=dataset_dir
)

builder = tfds.builder("imagenet2012")
builder.download_and_prepare(download_config=download_config)
```

- My Imagenet tar files are located in dataset_dir: /home/imagenet.
- Tar file names are : ILSVRC2012_img_train.tar and ILSVRC2012_img_val.tar
- Whenever I execute the above code, I get the following error:

DownloadError: Failed to get url http://www.image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2012/nnoupb/ILSVRC2012_img_train.tar. HTTP code: 404.

I am not sure why is it trying to download the Imagenet files. The DownloadConfig contains the manual_dir parameter which points to the location of the downloaded Imagenet tar files.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In TensorFlow [DataSetBuilder documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/core/DatasetBuilder#download_and_prepare), it is mentioned that the method `download_and_prepare` "downloads and prepares the dataset for reading".

Alternatively, you can use **tfds.load()** function to load the dataset that has already been downloaded.

According to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/load), **tfds.load()** comprises of following processes:

1. Fetch the **tfds.core.DataBuilder** by name
2. Generate the data (when download=True it will try to download, else it will look the data in local files)
3. Load the **tf.data.Dataset** object using `as_dataset` function.

You can utilize **tfds.load()** as follows:

```
dataset = tfds.load(
          'imagenet2012',
          split = ['train', 'val'], # or 'train' or 'val' if you need to load them seperately
          data_dir = dataset_dir,
          download = False
          )
```

More details can be found on the tfds.load() documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried tfds.load() but somehow even this method is not working for me. I keep getting the following assertion error:
AssertionError: Dataset imagenet2012: could not find data in /home/temp/data. Please make sure to call dataset_builder.download_and_prepare(), or pass download=True to tfds.load() before trying to access the tf.data.Dataset object.

I followed [link](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-train-a-neural-network-classifier-on-imagenet-using-tensorflow-2-ede0ea3a35ff) but even this method does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The method that finally worked for me is detailed in the following [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/issues/538#issuecomment-489679807).

Gist is as follows:

Download 2012 imagenet files  (ILSVRC2012_img_train.tar and ILSVRC2012_img_val.tar) and copy in ~/tensorflow_datasets/downloads

Rename files as:

```
imag-net.org_chal_LSVR_2012_nnou_ILSV_img_sIIAonqONCGKDlj942sP6Pc7w3f0rOotkWAgV8PKRbs.tar
```

Create the following file:

```
imag-net.org_chal_LSVR_2012_nnou_ILSV_img_sIIAonqONCGKDlj942sP6Pc7w3f0rOotkWAgV8PKRbs.tar.INFO
```

add the following metadata in the .INFO file:

```
{"dataset_names": ["imagenet2012_corrupted", "imagenet2012"], "original_fname": "ILSVRC2012_img_train.tar", "urls": ["http://www.image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2012/nnoupb/ILSVRC2012_img_train.tar"]}
```

For ILSVRC2012_img_val.tar, rename file as:

```
imag-net.org_chal_LSVR_2012_nnou_ILSV_img_x-BqbAuszwbY2-tld9ce__hGc6Xb3VBjOrRPjqBFauA.tar
```

Create the following file:

```
imag-net.org_chal_LSVR_2012_nnou_ILSV_img_x-BqbAuszwbY2-tld9ce__hGc6Xb3VBjOrRPjqBFauA.tar.INFO
```

add the following metadata in the .INFO file:

```
{"dataset_names": ["imagenet2012"], "original_fname": "ILSVRC2012_img_val.tar", "urls": ["http://www.image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2012/nnoupb/ILSVRC2012_img_val.tar"]}
```

I used the following code which used the pre-downloaded imagenet files:

```
data_dir = '/home/tensorflow_datasets/downloads/'  # directory where you downloaded the tar files
write_dir = '/home/temp'  # a temporary directory where the data will be stored intermediately

download_config = tfds.download.DownloadConfig(
    extract_dir=os.path.join(write_dir, 'extracted'),
    manual_dir=data_dir
)

builder = tfds.builder("imagenet2012")
builder.download_and_prepare(download_config=download_config)
```

Comment: Please include the essential part of the link in your answer